# Probability to get in two ways

Tags: probability

> There are $5$ pairs of socks: $2$ blue, $2$ white, $2$ black, $2$ yellow, $2$
> green. You select randomly four socks together. What is the
> probability that you'll get at least two of the same color?

The problem can be solved in the following way :

> Prob of at least getting a pair $=$ $1 -$ prob(all different at four
> attempts) $=$ $1-( 1 \times 8/9 \times 6/8 \times 4/7) = 1-8/21= 13/21$
>
> a) $1$ st attempt $=$ getting any color $=1$
>
> b) $2$nd attempt $=$ not getting the color picked in a). $= 8/9$
>
> c) $3$rd attempt $=$ not getting the two
> colors above $= 6/8$
>
> d) not getting any of the four colors above $= 4/7$

But if I want to  measure the  success  probability first  like:

Probability to get any color  $= 1$ , the the probability to get the same color $= 1/9$

Thus the probability to have same pair $= 1\times 1/9   =1/9$

**What is the problem with this?**

Comment: Your second method only takes two socks when in fact you take four.

Comment: So if we  do two more steps, then we get $1 \times  1/9 \times 1 \times 6/7 = 2/21 $

Comment: No.  You get $\frac{10}{10} \times \frac{1}{9} + \frac{10}{10} \times \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{2}{8} + \frac{10}{10} \times \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{6}{8}\times \frac{3}{7} = \frac{13}{21}$

Answer (score 0):

You start with

- Probability $1$ colour after $1$ sock: $1$
- Probability $2$ colours after $2$ socks: $1 \times \frac89 = \frac89$
- Probability $3$ colours after $3$ socks: $1 \times \frac89 \times \frac68 = \frac23$
- Probability $4$ colours after $4$ socks: $1 \times \frac89 \times \frac68 \times \frac47 = \frac8{21}$

and the original method would give

- Probability fewer than $2$ colours after $2$ socks: $1 - \frac89 = \frac19$
- Probability fewer than $3$ colours after $3$ socks: $1 - \frac23 = \frac13$
- Probability fewer than $4$ colours after $4$ socks: $1 - \frac8{21} = \frac{13}{21}$

while your method would give

- Probability fewer than $2$ colours after $2$ socks: $1 \times \frac19 = \frac19$
- Probability fewer than $3$ colours after $3$ socks: $\frac19 + \frac89 \times \frac28 = \frac13$
- Probability fewer than $4$ colours  after $4$ socks: $\frac13 + \frac23 \times \frac37 = \frac{13}{21}$

and they are the same answers.